# update variable to be used in another variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update the variable stateName whenever a SVG image of the state is clicked. I am able to access the name of the state, but I can't seem to update it within the parkEndpoint variable.

Here is an example of the one of the SVG's

```
        <path id="PA" data-info="<div>State: Pennsylvania</div> 
       <div>Capital: Harrisburg</div>" fill="#D3D3D3" 
    d="M996.2,326.5l1.1-0.6l2.3-0.6l1.5-2.7l1.6-2.3l3.2-3.1v-0.8l- 
    2.4-1.6l-3.6-2.4l-1-2.6l-2.7-0.3   l-0.2-1.1l-0.8-2.7l2.3- 
    1.1l0.2-2.4l-1.3-1.3l0.2-1.6l1.9-3.1v-3.1l2.3-2.4l0.2-1.1l-2.6- 
    0.2l-2.3-1.9l-2.4-5.3l-3-0.9l-2.3-2.1   l-18.6,4l-43,8.7l- 
    8.9,1.5l-0.5-7.1l-5.5,5.6l-1.3,0.5l- 
    4.2,3l2.9,19.1l2.5,9.7l3.6,19.3l3.3-0.6l11.9-1.5l37.9-7.7l14.9- 
    2.8   l8.3-1.6l0.3-0.2l2.1-1.6L996.2,326.5z"/>
```

And here is the JS

```
const alertEndpoint = ("https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/alerts? 
&limit=400&api_key=" + apikey );
const parkEndpoint = ("https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks? 
stateCode=" + stateName + "&limit=100&api_key=" + apikey);

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('path');
console.log(elements);

// add event listeners
elements.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click",  getStateName);

});


   function getStateName(nodeList){
   stateName = nodeList.path[0].id;
   outputStateName();

 }

   function outputStateName() {
   console.log(stateName);
   console.log(parkEndpoint);
  }
```

Comment: parkEndpoint is a constant, which means it shouldn't and can't be changed.

Comment: change the `const parkEndpoint` into a variable `var parkEndpoint`

Comment: stupid mistake...changed to a var but still will not update.

Comment: You  need to add `stateName` to the parameter list of `outputStateName`, and send it when calling from `getStateName`. (like `outputStateName(stateName)`)

Comment: still did not update. I am able to output the stateName in outputStateName, but a line below when I output parkEndpoint, it still returns empty in the URL

Comment: so it does update when I call it in the console, but it won't update when I call the parkEndpoint variable.